# Polish Wheat Purchase

Tags: gluten-free

I was diagnosed as gluten intolerant but they said I could use Polish Wheat.  I was wondering if anybody knew where I could purchase this in the US?

Comment: looks like it might have to be imported -- https://hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/Crops/Wheat.html : " Polish wheat, Triticum polonicum L.
Polish wheat varieties are spring wheats with tall stems. Spikes are large, open or dense, awned, and square or rectangular in cross-section. Kernels are very long, narrow, and hard. They thresh free of the glumes. While grown extensively in Mediterranean countries, Polish wheat has proved inferior in the United States both in yield and in quality for bread or macaroni products. For these reasons it has substantially disappeared from commercial production."

Comment: Joe,  thank you for the information.  I guess I have to go with the rice flours and give up on good bread.